# Formatting cell value in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have number of hours `02:30`, and I want to parse it to `2.5` automatically when I place it to cell. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You're going to get a lot more help if you post some code of you trying to do that.  I think you want to take the minutes and divide by 60 and add the hours, and add the seconds divided by 3600, but I'm not certain of how to do that in google-spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a four-step process. You need four formulas. Broken down into steps they are as follows.

Start by placing `2:30` in cell `A1` then proceed as follows.

```
A2=HOUR(A1)   // Step 1. Get hours
A3=MINUTE(A1) // Step 2. Get minutes
A4=A3/60      // Step 3. Get minutes as fraction of hour
A5=A2+A4      // Step 4. Add step 1 result to step 3 result
```

Or you could combine it all into one big function:

```
B1=HOUR(A1)+(MINUTE(A1)/60)
```

[Here is a link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BO4B6NYzES8xRjroCmTUbTbc1h6I8un440TXPAsii7E/edit?usp=sharing) to the spreadsheet that proves the above is correct.

Comment: thansk. but i need to do it in single cell

Comment: Ok. Then just use the formula in the part of the answer underneath "Or you could combine it all into one big function." In other words, the formula would be `B1=HOUR(A1)+(MINUTE(A1)/60)`

Answer (score 1):

Does this formula work as you want:

`=VALUE("02:30")*24`

You can replace the "02:30" with a cell reference or a formula that outputs that value